# Override version of transitive dependencies in Maven

Tags: maven, pom.xml

I have the following in my pom

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
            <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.3</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.spockframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spock-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-groovy-2.4</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>org.codehaus.groovy</artifactId>
                    <groupId>groovy-all</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.spockframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spock-spring</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-groovy-2.4</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>org.codehaus.groovy</artifactId>
                    <groupId>groovy-all</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
```

Basically, I want to force my second and third dependencies to use the version of groovy-all that I'm setting in my first dependency. Is there a better way to do this than setting an exclusion on each of them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since as a first dependency you're explicitly defining a version of the `groovy-all` dependency, this will override the version of this dependency for all transitive dependencies needing this exact dependency. Hence, you won't have to define explicit exclusions.

To validate this, you can run the following before and after the change:

```
mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose
```

And compare the output.

Answer (score 0):

Fix is to lock down the version, either via a direct dependency, or a dependency-management section.